# How to disable a "dijit.form.FilteringSelect" widget?

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I cannot find a way to disable the dijit.form.FilteringSelect widget. The requirement makes the css display as none is not an option.

Any hint? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Figure it out myself:

```
dijit.byId('_fromState_id').set('disabled', true);
```

simply does the job. Change it to `false` can enable the widget.

Cheers.

**UPDATE**

Plus, there is another attribute to the widget called `"readOnly"`, the difference from it and `"disabled"` is that :

1. `disabled` does not allow any value given to the widget, meaning the widget value is always `NULL("")` in the form. It might be a problem in `NotNull` situation;
2. but `readOnly` allows to preset a value to the widget and make it not editable, and user can still submit the value just only not able to change it.

sample:

```
  dijit.byId("_fromState_id").set("value", "NOTAVAILABLE");
  dijit.byId('_fromState_id').set('readOnly', true);
```

Comment: Correct, mark as your answer so others may possibly benifit from it ^^ all dijit.form widgets has that feature :)

Comment: @mschr Thank you. Good to know that as a newbie on Dojo